# R ignores 0 values

Tags: r, histogram

I am trying to create some descriptive statistics and histograms out of ordered variables (range 0 to 10). I used the following commands:

```
class(data$var1)
describe(as.numeric(data$var1))
```

But R starts from 1 and counts the "refusal" values as a further numeric value.

How can I let R start from 0 and ignore the "refusal" values?

Thank you.

Edit: I was able to let R ignore "refusal" value using the following command:

```
is.na (data$var1[data$var1=="Refusal"]) <- TRUE
```

But when I search for possible solution about the 0 values I am only finding suggestion on how to ignore/remove 0 values...

Edit2: This is a sample of my data,

```
 [1] 5       8       8       8       Refusal 10      8       Refusal 7      
  [10] 7       8       7       8       8       8       8       8       8      
  [19] 8       0       9       Refusal 6       10      7       7       9
```

as you can see the range is from 0 to 10 but using the R library "psych" and the command "describe" the output range is always 1 to 11 and this invalidates the whole statistics.

```
> class(data$var1)
[1] "factor"
> describe(as.numeric(data$var1), na.rm=TRUE)
  vars    n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range  skew kurtosis   se
1    1 1115 8.38 1.94      9    8.57 1.48   1  11    10 -1.06     1.42 0.06
```

Sorry for the ongoing editing but I am new of stackoverflow.com

Comment: Sorry, I missed a bracket:

<code> 
class(data$var1)
describe(as.numeric(data$var1))

Comment: Thank you, docendo discimus. :-)

Comment: Its not very reproducible is it?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please read [about how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to provide a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the output of the code that you've included? If the first line is `"factor"` you could try `describe(as.numeric(as.character(data$var1))` so that conversion from factor to number works as you expect.

Comment: This is the output after I removed the "refusal" values:

> class(dataset$MCZ_1)
[1] "factor"
> describe(as.numeric(dataset$MCZ_1), na.rm=TRUE)
  vars    n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range  skew kurtosis   se
1    1 1115 8.38 1.94      9    8.57 1.48   1  11    10 -1.06     1.42 0.06

So the "refusal" value have been successfully removed, but I still get a range from 1 to 11, despite the original one is from 0 to 10.

Comment: @Crescenzo - check my code again. it converts to character, then to numeric. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you, Miff. 
I tried both your code and the one I've just modified and mine is working now with regards to the character values.
But I still have issue with the range of values that the output statistics wrongly considers starting from 1 rather than 0.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how factors work, with `?factor`, or looking at the example [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information). In essence, each level is given a number starting at 1, hence ending at 11 if you have 11 unique values. Conversion of a factor to numeric returns these codes, rather than the underlying numbers they relate to. To do this, first convert to character, then to numeric. See the difference between these code snippets:

```
#create data
set.seed(0)
a <- factor(sample(c(0:10,"refusal"),50,T)) #Some dummy data
class(a)
# [1] "factor"
```

snippet 1 - how you're doing it

```
describe(as.numeric(a),na.rm=TRUE)
#as.numeric(a) 
#n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90     .95 
#50       0      11    6.28    2.00    2.00    4.00    6.00    8.75   10.00   11.00 
#
#1  2  3 4 5  6  7  8 9 10 11
#Frequency 2  5  5 4 2  8  6  5 3  6  4
#%         4 10 10 8 4 16 12 10 6 12  8
```

snippet 2 - correct way

```
describe(as.numeric(as.character(a)),na.rm=TRUE)
#as.numeric(as.character(a)) 
#n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90     .95 
#46       4      10   5.304     1.0     1.0     3.0     5.0     8.0     9.5    10.0 
#
#0  1 2 3  4  5  7 8  9 10
#Frequency 2  5 4 2  8  6  5 3  6  5
#%         4 11 9 4 17 13 11 7 13 11
#Warning message:
#  In describe(as.numeric(as.character(a)), na.rm = TRUE) :
#  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Note the difference in range (even if my `describe` function isn't the same as yours). The warning refers to the "refusals which are converted to `NAs` as they don't represent a number

Comment: Thank you, Miff. 
There was a bracket missing (again, my fault) and that's why your code didn't work properly the first time.
Thank you also for your explanation, now I can see where I was wrong.
I hope I can be as helpful as you in the future when R will be less "problematic". 
:-)